# Check if a string has no characters or numbers at all

Tags: php

In php, how can I check if a string has no characters at all.

Currently I do like below, and replace `-` with `' '`. But if a search string contained all bad words, it'll leave me with `'   '`(3 blank spaces). The length will still show as 3 and it'll head off to the sql processor. Any method to check if a string has no characters or numbers at all?

```
$fetch = false;

#$strFromSearchBox = 'Why-you-foo-bar-I-ought-to-tar-you';
$strFromSearchBox = 'foo-bar-tar';

if(strlen($strFromSearchBox) >=2)
{
    $newString = str_replace($theseWords,'',$strFromSearchBox);
    $newString = str_replace('-',' ',$newString);

    if(strlen($newString)>=2)
    {   
        $fetch = true;
        echo $newString;
    }
}


if($fetch){echo 'True';}else{echo 'False';}
```

Comment: Can you explain *"if a search string contained all bad words"*... I don't understand. What are you really after here?

Comment: Please browse the [PHP list of string functions first](http://php.net/ref.strings), it might just contain what you're looking for, e.g. http://php.net/trim

Comment: My bad words are in an array.

Comment: You mean like, curse words?

Comment: Yes curse words. Oh! what seems to be happening to me. Why didn't trim come to my mind?

Comment: Just a heads up: Your method of filtering words can be broken easily, as order of replacement is very relevant with str_replace: http://codepad.org/LMuhFH4g

Comment: @WesleyMurch +1 for the example ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$fetch = false;

#$strFromSearchBox = 'Why-you-foo-bar-I-ought-to-tar-you';
$strFromSearchBox = 'foo-bar-tar';

if(strlen($strFromSearchBox) >=2)
{
    $newString = str_replace($theseWords,'',$strFromSearchBox);
    $newString = str_replace('-',' ',$newString);
    $newString=trim($newString);  //This will make the string 0 length if all are spaces
    if(strlen($newString)>=2)
    {   
        $fetch = true;
        echo $newString;
    }
}


if($fetch){echo 'True';}else{echo 'False';}
```

Comment: Thanks, Hanky Panky. I definitely need to rest.

Answer (score 2):

If you strip the leading and backmost spaces, the length will go down to 0 which you can easily turn into the `$fetch` boolean:

```
$fetch = (bool) strlen(trim($newString));
```

See [`trim`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/trim).

Answer (score 1):

Use regex perhaps...

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/', $strFromSearchBox))
{
  //is true that $strFromSearchBox contains letters and/or numbers
}
```